# C# triangle of numbers descending

Tags: c#

I am working on one job and i need your help. I need triangle of numbers, **just like the one on the bottom**. I know there is perhaps only one or maybe two steps to solution, but i am struggling with this problem for hours..

My code so far is:

```
        for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++)
        {
            for (int k = 1; k <= i; k++)
            {
                Console.Write(k);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("");
        }
```

1

21

321

4321

54321

654321

7654321

87654321

987654321

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: `for (int k= i; k>0; --k)` your order is wrong. You need to output them from 9 to 1, not for 1 to 9 as you're currently doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to print your numbers from the biggest to the smallest you have to make your second loop that way. Currently your second loop prints from `1` to `i`, but you want to print them in decreasing order, so it makes sense to print them from `i` to `1` like this:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++)
{
    for (int k = i; k >= 1; k--)
    {
        Console.Write(k);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("");
}
```